Hyperledger Caliper run has some wrong
enter image description here
and i run the hyperledger-fabric test network,but when i  checked used peer lifestyle chaincode
enter image description here
it is also run.(Maybe this code should run in the peer docker container?)
i hope somebody can fixed my problem,and make me can test the fabric network by hyperledger caliper

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

mmyAssetBenchmark.yaml
test:
    name: basic-contract-benchmark
    description: test benchmark
    workers:
      type: local
      number: 2
    rounds:
      - label: readAsset
        description: Read asset benchmark
        txDuration: 30
        rateControl: 
          type: fixed-load
          opts:
            transactionLoad: 2
        workload:
          module: workload/readAsset.js
          arguments:
            assets: 10
            contractId: basic

monitors:
  resource:
  - module: docker
    options:
      interval: 5 
      containers:
      - all

networkConfig.yaml
name: Caliper Benchmarks
version: "2.0.0"
 
caliper:
  blockchain: fabric
 
channels:
  - channelName: mychannel
    contracts:
    - id: basic

organizations:
  - mspid: Org1MSP
    # Identities come from cryptogen created material for test-network
    identities:
      certificates:
      - name: 'User1'
        clientPrivateKey:
          path: '/home/hokori/hyperledge-fabric/samples/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/msp/keystore/priv_sk'
        clientSignedCert:
          path: '/home/hokori/hyperledge-fabric/samples/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/msp/cacerts/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem'
    connectionProfile:
      path: '/home/hokori/hyperledge-fabric/samples/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/connection-org1.yaml'
      discover: true

readAsset.js
'use strict';
 
const { WorkloadModuleBase } = require('@hyperledger/caliper-core');
 
class MyWorkload extends WorkloadModuleBase {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    
    async initializeWorkloadModule(workerIndex, totalWorkers, roundIndex, roundArguments, sutAdapter, sutContext) {
        await super.initializeWorkloadModule(workerIndex, totalWorkers, roundIndex, roundArguments, sutAdapter, sutContext);
 
        for (let i=0; i<this.roundArguments.assets; i++) {
            const assetID = `${this.workerIndex}_${i}`;
            console.log(`Worker ${this.workerIndex}: Creating asset ${assetID}`);
            const request = {
                contractId: this.roundArguments.contractId,
                contractFunction: 'CreateAsset',
                invokerIdentity: 'Admin@org1.example.com',
                contractArguments: [assetID,'blue','20','penguin','500'],
                readOnly: false
            };
 
            await this.sutAdapter.sendRequests(request);
        }
    }
    
    async submitTransaction() {
        const randomId = Math.floor(Math.random()*this.roundArguments.assets);
        const myArgs = {
            contractId: this.roundArguments.contractId,
            contractFunction: 'ReadAsset',
            invokerIdentity: 'Admin@org1.example.com',
            contractArguments: [`${this.workerIndex}_${randomId}`],
            readOnly: true
        };
 
        await this.sutAdapter.sendRequests(myArgs);
    }
    
    async cleanupWorkloadModule() {
        for (let i=0; i<this.roundArguments.assets; i++) {
            const assetID = `${this.workerIndex}_${i}`;
            console.log(`Worker ${this.workerIndex}: Deleting asset ${assetID}`);
            const request = {
                contractId: this.roundArguments.contractId,
                contractFunction: 'DeleteAsset',
                invokerIdentity: 'Admin@org1.example.com',
                contractArguments: [assetID],
                readOnly: false
            };
 
            await this.sutAdapter.sendRequests(request);
        }
    }
}
 
function createWorkloadModule() {
    return new MyWorkload();
}
 
module.exports.createWorkloadModule = createWorkloadModule;


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
